# How do I turn dash breaks in file name into new directories with Apache mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'd like to use Apache's mod_rewrite in order to treat all dash breaks within a file name as separate folders starting from the top, or vice versa.

For example, if someone was to access `/events/booking/?id=1` the file `events-booking.php?id=1` would actually be requested.

The current sceript I have is taken from the StackOverflow post below, which simply strips the file of it's extension, but I'd like the addition of the above too.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1698807/2023781

Any help on how to modify my existing block of mod_rewrite script would be greatly appreciated (I'm not really good with regex yet unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, this should do it:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /$1-$2.php [L]`

`^` = beginning of path

`([^/]*)` = match all characters except slash

`$` = end of path

`$1` and `$2` are the two matched strings from the path.

The query string should carry over as-is.