# The following modrewrite is generating a server error and I can't work out why

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

The following .htacess file is throwing up a server error on every url, and is also breaking the images / css references.

This modrewrite has been taken from [Neil Crosby's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205096/neilcrosby) answer
[mod_rewrite to remove .php but still serve the .php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698464/mod-rewrite-to-remove-php-but-still-serve-the-php-file)

With the only change being that I have changed the domain to a .co.nz domain name.

What I need to have happen is:

For this solution, I have followed the following rules:

1. If the user tries to load /something.php they should be externally redirected to /something/.
2. If the user tries to load /something then they should be internally redirected to /something.php.
3. If the user passed any query string parameters to the URL then these should be preserved through the redirects.
4. If the user tries to load a different file which really exists on the filesystem (a stylesheet, image etc) then this should be loaded as is.

This is exactly as the modrewrite is supposed to be, except it is throwing the server error.

In addition to this, I was wanting to check that there are directories or subdirectories referred to, so I would have thought that the following addition would fix this also.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This is the original modrewrite, and this is throwing a server error for:
- main URL (eg no trailing slash)
- a direct file which exists (eg /file-name.php)
- a real directory which exists (eg /directory, and that directory contains an index)
- the css and images which are in different directories and they appear to be getting broken.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

## Always use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.nz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co\.nz/$1 [L,R=301]

# Change urlpath.php to urlpath
## Only perform this rule if we're on the expected domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.co\.nz$ [NC]

## Don't perform this rule if we've already been redirected internally
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !internal=1 [NC]

## Redirect the user externally to the non PHP URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [L,R=301]

# if the user requests /something we need to serve the php version if it exists

## Only perform this rule if we're on the expected domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.co\.nz$ [NC]

## Perform this rule only if a file with this name does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

## Perform this rule if the requested file doesn't end with '.php'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$ [NC]

## Only perform this rule if we're not requesting the index page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$

## Finally, rewrite the URL internally, passing through the user's query string
## using the [qsa] flag along with an 'internal=1' identifier so that our first
## RewriteRule knows we've already redirected once.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?internal=1 [L, QSA]
```

Also my basic understanding of modrewrite and regex is pretty minimal, so any assistance with breaking out each command and it's meaning would also be really appreciated.

Comment: Enable the mod_rewrite log and see what's going on. I suspect 1 and 2 are causing a redirect loop.

Comment: I am getting the logs, and will have a look.