# .htaccess url rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my `.htaccess`. It redirects `/contact` to `index.php?page=contact`
This works perfectly. But with this `.htaccess`, if someone puts `/contact.php`, they'll get an error.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1  [QSA]
```

Basically, is there any way to only rewrite if there's no `.php` in the URL?
If there's a `.php` in the URL, e.g. `contact.php` just load the normal `.php` page.

How could I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod\_rewrite to remove .php but still serve the .php file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698464/mod-rewrite-to-remove-php-but-still-serve-the-php-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add something like this before the RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

-f means "is a file". With this rule you are saying "requested file name is not an existing file" (in the DocumentRoot, ofc).

More info and options: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Thanks for that! Could you help me for the 2nd part?

Comment: Try this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$ [NC]` (source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698464/mod-rewrite-to-remove-php-but-still-serve-the-php-file)