# Laravel, mod_rewrite, and removing .php extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I've begun the process of rebuilding a site within Laravel 4.

The URLs of this site are currently served with the .php extension. Customers have these pages bookmarked so it's important I redirect them to the same page minus the .php extension.

Example: I would like `/contact.php` to redirect to `/contact`.

Laravel ships with this in its htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm not well versed in regular expressions or Apache's own syntax. I found [this comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698464/mod-rewrite-to-remove-php-but-still-serve-the-php-file) to serving php files without the .php extension, but Laravel routes everything through index.php, so that solution doesn't seem to work.

How do I universally redirect URLs with .php to the same page without the extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above the rules that you already have, add this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

to redirect non-existent php pages.